# Subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with some property is countable or uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that for given any $\epsilon >0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exist $y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ with $y \in S$ and $z \notin S,$ such that $|x-y| < \epsilon$ and $|x-z| < \epsilon$. What can we say about $S$, is it countable or uncountable?  I think $S$ can be both countable and uncountable as rational and irrational numbers can work here.

Comment: You have the right answer.

Comment: You're just saying that, topologically, both $S$ and $\Bbb R\setminus S$ are dense. As you said, both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ have this property, and with some tweaks to this idea you should be able to prove that there is one for each cardinal between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ (as many as there may be).

Comment: Thanks, that means I was thinking in the right direction.